# Getting "Object expected but got string" error when trying to save in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, parameters, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 5.  I have this model

```
class ConfidentialMemo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :scenario
  belongs_to :scenario_role
end
```

In my view, I have this drop down set up for selecting a field to be populated into the “scneairo_role” field …

```
<%= f.collection_select :scenario_role, @scenario.roles, :id, :name, include_blank: false %>
```

In the create method of my controller, I have this

```
@confidential_memo = ConfidentialMemo.new(confidential_memo_params)
…

  private

    def confidential_memo_params
      params.require(:confidential_memo).permit(:description, :scenario_id, :scenario_role)
    end
```

but I’m getting the error

```
ScenarioRole(#70207639353420) expected, got String(#70207645188180)
```

What does this error mean and more importantly, what do I need to adjust tis save my model successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Change `:scenario_role` to `:scenario_role_id` in your collection_select method and in your controller params method. Your form is outputting and sending an id (in the form of a string), but if you just try to assign an id to `@note.scenario_role`, it'll fail with the same type of message.

Comment: Per your advice, I changed my select menu to "<%= f.collection_select :scenario_role_id, @scenario.roles, :id, :name, include_blank: false %>" but then got the error, "undefined method `scenario_role_id' for #<ConfidentialMemo:0x007fdf13136060>"

Comment: Ooookay. Do you have migrations for this ConfidentialMemo object? How does it relate to the scenario role? is there a relationship table column?